# Return MAX date of two cells, IF BLANK return "need to complete"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having trouble figuring out a formula to accomplish this. Tried a lot of different things.

Return MAX date of (R3,T3) IF BLANK return "need to complete". Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OR to test if blank

```
=IF(OR(R3="",T3=""),"Need to complete",MAX(R3,T3))
```